# Cannot create a .Net object in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell

I am a beginner in PowerShell scripting.
I have tried to create a .Net object by executing the following command but it fails :

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>]$myList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>
```

An error message informs me the type [System.Collections.Generic.List] has not been found.
The error message also informs me I should check if the assembly containing the type is loaded.

I guess I have to load the assembly containing the type [System.Collections.Generic.List] but I do not know how to do it.

I also want to know from which .Net framework version I can use types in PowerShell.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Types and Type parameters are delimited with square brackets, not angled ones.

```
$myList = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]'
```